# Polymer designer code generation flow?

Tags: polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I am working on re-purposing the designer with my custom elements added to the palette.

In the generated code the ids for the elements are obviously created from the element name and then a digit is appended based on how many you add.

I want to generate these ids differently and then hide them from the user Property list; but I cannot see where in the code they are being created.

​Seems that it would be in design-canvas.html or in design-code.html but if so, which function?  ​

​Any pointers to where this code is located would be appreciated. ​

Answer (score 1):

Answered on IRC [link to GitHub repo](https://github.com/Polymer/designer/blob/989c35a125b302a0c3036b3cd107383290b2a480/elements/design-canvas/design-canvas.html#L428)